# Windows 7 cannot find a WiFi network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection

My Windows 7 desktop computer cannot connect to my WiFi network when I go home. It works fine for other WiFi networks and if I boot into Ubuntu it can find the network perfectly. Why does Windows 7 refuse to find this network? What can I try?

Network Details:

- Router: Netgear DG834G
- Broadcasting SSID
- MAC Address control on
- Encryption: WPA-PSK+WPA2-PSK
- Band: b/g

Comment: Can you tell us more about the network? In what ways does it differ from other networks? What is the band, a/b/g/n? Router Name / Model, etc.

Comment: Is the network marked as hidden?

Comment: Added some details about the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, the wireless channel was set to 13 which the wifi card didn't support

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some driver issues. Download the latest network drivers for you NIC. Then uninstall the Wireless NIC drivers and install the latest. Hardware wise, it sound as if it works since it is working.

Another possibility, sort of an unlikely one, is if this is the same laptop that you use at work then it is possible that there are settings or 3rd-party applications installed to prevent you from connecting to WiFi network. This would be due to company IT policies. If this is the case, then it is likely that it would only effect Windows 7 because it is rare to allow a personal Linux laptop on a corporate *Windows* domain network.

*Please don't assume it is the latter reason unless know for sure. I don't want you accusing your IT department at your work for something that doesn't apply to your system or company's policies.*

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing either AES or TKIP.  I have issues if I let Windows or the driver auto select this setting.